# How to set default language in google forms to do survey from different browsers

Tags: google-forms, google-form-quiz

Here, i created google form with 9 questions for conducting local survey. All the 9 questions typed in "Telugu"   language except the title and the sub titles are in "English".
But in my google chrome, its displaying with the Telugu language where as its not working for Firefox and in IE for me.

When the local survey team opening up a link in their browsers(tab), they are getting up some other language( boxes) for only this 9 questions, but titles with English are remained in their language itself.

I had tried even by adding &hl=te, **hl=te**, hl=te and ?hl=te. Even though the form is not displaying with the required language.
Can any one help me out of this?

[Google_View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GgUdy.png)

[Firefox_view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTp9o.png)

[Here is the link]https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSc_5ehz6C8lF_igcmgLsDbewBSnW_Qqy0PdCzkd4E6WHjR5_Q/viewform

Comment: Please rephrase your question, as of now, it doesn't look like a programming question, but rather one of google forms usage.

Comment: I think that this question should be asked on [su] as it looks that the issue depends on how the each web browser is displaying the form.